# string to char array, showing silly characters

Tags: java, arrays, string, char, to-char

It is a really simple question but I need an another eye to look at my code:

```
String strtr = "iNo:";
char[] queryNo = strtr.toCharArray();
System.out.println(queryNo + " =this is no");
```

and the output is:

```
[C@177b4d3 =this is no
```

What are these characters, *do you have any idea*?

Comment: what is the expected output?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's how `toString()` is implemented for arrays.

The `[C` denotes that is a char array, `177b4d3` is its hashcode.

You may want to look at

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(queryNo) + " =this is no");
```

if you want to see your original String again, you need this:

```
System.out.println((new String(queryNo)) + " =this is no");
```

Comment: so are you saying it is normal? Shouldnt I see "iNo =this is no" I need to see the sting that I declare at the beggining

Comment: @hassasin.. Then why not just print the string. You are aware that `string` and a `char array` are two different things right?

Comment: really thanks. I got these:
[i, N, o, :] =this is no
iNo: =this is the original no
So I have the char array correctly, but when I want to print this char array I should use tostring or new String, right?

Comment: `toString()` would give you what you had, `new String()` what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays do not override toString(), it is inherited from Object.toString as

```
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you are printing the object

`queryno`, as `queryno` is a character array of on dimension and java is an object oriented language which holds every thing in the form of classes it gives the **class name** `[C` to your array where `[` **denotes total dimension** and `C` **denotes character type** of array, **Rest** is the **hashcode** of the object.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to print the **array** and that is the reason you get gibberish. Try using `Arrays.toString(queryNo)` and you will see what you expected.