# What does the output of a printed character array mean?

Tags: java, string, character-arrays

I'm moving from C to Java now and I was following some tutorials regarding Strings. At one point in the tutorials they showed instantiating a new string from a character array then printing the string. I was following along, but I wanted to print both the character array and the string so I tried this:

```
class Whatever {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        char[] hello = { 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '.'};
        String hello_str = new String(hello);
        System.out.println(hello + " " + hello_str);
    }
}
```

My output was something like this:

```
[C@9304b1 hello.
```

Clearly, this is not how you would print a character array in Java. However I'm wondering if I just got garbage? I read on some site that printing a character array give you an address, but that doesn't look like an address to me... I haven't found a lot online about it.

So, what did I just print?

and bonus questions:
How do you correctly print a character array in java?

Comment: possible duplicate of [string to char array, showing silly characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13641462/string-to-char-array-showing-silly-characters)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> However I'm wondering if I just got garbage?

No, you got the result of [`Object.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29), which isn't overridden in arrays:

> The toString method for class Object returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal to the value of:
>
> ```
> getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
> ```

So it's not *garbage*, in that it has a meaning... but it's not a particularly *useful* value, either.

And your bonus question...

> How do you correctly print a character array in java?

Call [`Arrays.toString(char[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28char%5B%5D%29) to convert it to a string... or just

```
System.out.println(hello);
```

which will call `println(char[])` instead, which converts it into a string. Note that `Arrays.toString` will build a string which is obviously an array of characters, whereas `System.out.println(hello)` is broadly equivalent to `System.out.println(new String(hello))`

Comment: @JonSkeet.. Surprisingly, if we print the character array before creating a string out of it, we get the `hello.` as result. Why a different behaviour in printing before the creation of string, and after that?

Comment: @RohitJain: That sounds unlikely to me. I suspect you're misdiagnosing it.

Comment: @JonSkeet.. `char[] hello = { 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '.'};
  System.out.println(hello);
        String hello_str = new String(hello);
        System.out.println(hello + " " + hello_str);` This code is working strangely. :(

Comment: @RohitJain: That's calling `println(char[])` rather than `println(Object)`, so it's not calling `toString()`. Try changing it to `"" + hello` (for example) and you'll see the original output.

Comment: @JonSkeet perhaps you should mention `println(char[])` in the answer.

Comment: Neat answer. I thought it was hex, but the `@` and the `[` were throwing me. So a character array is of class `[C`? That's a weird class name...

Comment: @Mike: `[` indicates an array, and `C` is the short name for the `char` primitive type. (See the docs for `Class.getName()` for details.)