# initialise a array in one class and make accessible to another

Tags: java, arrays

this may seem daft i have a class called ship locations which i wish to store all my ships locations, ive extended it from my client class and simply called the set method as follows 
sub.local being a multidimensional array from the ship class

```
sub.local = new int[2][2];  
sub.local[0][0] =row;
sub.local[0][1]=col;
sub.local[1][0]=row;
sub.local[1][1] =col+1;

toServer.writeInt(row);
toServer.writeInt(col);
toServer.writeChar('s');


sub.placed=true;
setp1sub(sub.local);
```

When i print it back through another class it comes back with the location in the memory rather than the numbers i need. What is the reason for this

```
public class ShipLocations {


static int [][] p1sub;

public ShipLocations()
{
    p1sub = new int[2][2];
}
public int[][] getp1sub()
{
    return p1sub;
}
public void setp1sub(int[][] local) {
    for (int i = 0;i <local.length;i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0;j<local.length;j++)
        {
            p1sub [i][j]= local[i][j];
        }
    }

}



}
```

would it be that im passing it as sub.local ?
output is [[I@a401c2

Comment: Can you show us the print statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of writing

```
System.out.println(yourArray);
```

use

```
// for multidemensional arrays:
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(yourArray));
// or for one dimemsional arrays:
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(yourArray));
```

Here is a link to the relevant [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29).

For an explanation of your output, you can look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13641462/string-to-char-array-showing-silly-characters/13641478#13641478).

Comment: thank you but would that mean i can only retrieve my array as a string not as a int [][] also, printing the array the out put is [[0, 0], [0, 0]] all the time which isnt right

Comment: what do you mean by retrieve?

Comment: i intend to read this and compare this to another array, but the values (if both have identical values then the ship has been hit) however currently my main concern is that it stays at [[0,0][0,0]]

Comment: @jbel you can use it like you want. `if(array[0][0] == otherArray[0][0])` or any other way you want. Your problem was with the output beeing `[[I@a401c2`. That's output for `System.out.println(array);`. I showed you a way to get nice output. If you have a different problem, feel free to write a new question.