# Why map function in scala not reading Arrays

Tags: scala

I am very new to scala programming , hence asking this question

My scala program is below

```
object FirstMain{

 def main(args: Array[String]): Unit={

 val myArray = Array(1,2,3,4)
 val k =myArray.map(x => x*10)
 println(k)
}


}
```

Why I am getting output as [I@14991ad

I want the array elements to be read and want each element to be multiplied with 10 and print the result

Also I would like to know what is the return type of map() in scala

Comment: `[I@14991ad` *is* that new array. Arrays don't print their elements like `List`s do. Try using `List(1,2,3,4)` instead of `Array(1,2,3,4)`, especially if you are a beginner and don't know completely understand the difference yet.

Comment: yes got it .. tried printing like k(0), K(1).. it prints.. also tried with List(1,2,3,4) it prints all in one print statement. Thanks for your help

Comment: On the other question of the reutrn type for "map()" in scala: You might be interested in reading [How are Scala collections able to return the correct collection type from a map operation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200505/how-are-scala-collections-able-to-return-the-correct-collection-type-from-a-map) and more specifically w.r.t. Arrays: [Scala Doc of Collections - Arrays](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/arrays)

Comment: if you just want to see the result and you don't want to use List, do `println(k.mkString(", "))`. It will convert your entries in the array to string and will therefore be easier to see when you are using println.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Array` is a Scala's way of representing Java arrays. Invoking `Array.toString()` method (which you do implicitly in `println(k)`) invokes `toString` method defined in Java's `Object` class (which by default prints hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object). You should try using Scala's `List` type, which overrides `toString()` method and outputs pretty contents of the list.

```
val list = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
println(list) // Prints: `List(1, 2, 3, 4)`
```

You can also easily convert an `Array` to a `List`:

```
val list = Array(1, 2, 3, 4).toList
```

For your second question: mapping an `Array` returns another `Array`.

Answer (score 2):

Array.map will return another Array

```
println(k) <=> println(String.valueOf(k)) <=> println(k.toString)
```

the `Array` does not override the method of `toString`
if you want to print your array like this `Array(10, 20, 30, 40)`, you can use the following code

```
println(k.deep)
```

`deep` not in Scala 2.13 see [SO answer about Array deep documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56918200/101954).

Good luck with you

Answer (score 2):

`map` builds a new collection by applying a function to all elements of this array.

To print an Array you can do the following :

```
val myArray = Array(1, 2, 3, 4)
// myArray: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4)

val k = myArray.map(x => x * 10)
// k: Array[Int] = Array(10, 20, 30, 40)

println(k.mkString("[", ",", "]"))
// [10,20,30,40]
```

Hence, you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13641478/3415409) what does actually `[I@14991ad` means. (Array of Integer with hashcode of the Array object `14991ad`)