# Locating Scala Array deep documentation?

Tags: scala, documentation

[SO answer by Jerry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37613835) includes this use of `deep`:

```
println(k.deep)
```

Works as described:

```
scala> println(Array(10, 20, 30, 40).deep)
Array(10, 20, 30, 40)
```

I am looking for documentation on `deep` for an `Array`.  I go to [Scala Standard Library 2.13.0 Array](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Array.html) and do a search of the page for `deep`and get no matches.

[image: Scala Array w search for 'deep']

How is this the incorrect sequence?

Answer (score 5):

It seems it has been removed from Scala 2.13 according to https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/10985:

> It's a hacky ugly testing utility to print values in (nested) arrays.
>   If you feel strongly about it, we can add it deprecated.

You can still find it in [2.12 docs](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/Array.html#deep:IndexedSeq[Any]) and in [2.12 branch](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/1be284c4f1b65ed4543a45a24403222f6e402fd5/src/library/scala/collection/mutable/ArrayLike.scala#L29):

```
  /** Creates a possible nested `IndexedSeq` which consists of all the elements
   *  of this array. If the elements are arrays themselves, the `deep` transformation
   *  is applied recursively to them. The `stringPrefix` of the `IndexedSeq` is
   *  "Array", hence the `IndexedSeq` prints like an array with all its
   *  elements shown, and the same recursively for any subarrays.
   *
   *  Example:
   *  {{{
   *  Array(Array(1, 2), Array(3, 4)).deep.toString
   *  }}}
   *  prints: `Array(Array(1, 2), Array(3, 4))`
   *
   *  @return    An possibly nested indexed sequence of consisting of all the elements of the array.
   */
  def deep: scala.collection.IndexedSeq[Any]
```

Comment: Is there a more direct route to finding the change, besides tracking back thru release notes for all old versions until stumbling upon the info?

Comment: Try searching the main repo https://github.com/scala/scala, for example https://github.com/scala/scala/search?q=deep+array&unscoped_q=deep+array&type=Issues